# How to add item in rxjs observable array in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an angular service that consumes rest api.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  private url: string = "/app/products";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  get(caregoryId: string) {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${this.url}`)
      .pipe(map(products => products.filter(p => p.caregoryId == caregoryId)))
  }

  add(p: Product) {
    return this.http.post<Product>(this.url, p);
  }
}
```

And my component is:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{

     items: Observable<Array<Product>>;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
          (params: any) => {
            this.items = this.productService.get(params.id);            
          })
     }

    addWidget() {
        let item: any = { name: "p-1", color: "red" } }

        this.productService.add(item))
        /// how to add created item in my items array ?

    }
}
```

I can get list of products and list them using async pipe in html. But I could not add the created item in my observable array. How can I do it?

Comment: You're missing the `subscribe` in `this.productService.add(item)`.

Comment: @developer033 OP is returing the observable so they're probably subscribing to it elsewehere

Comment: @barteloma please, could you check if my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of reassigning the `items$` every time you perform an operation in list (add, remove, update, etc.), you could use [**`rxjs#Subject`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject), [**`rxjs#merge`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) and [**`rxjs#scan`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan) to control the data flow;
2. You don't have to manually subscribe to route param changes, you could just use [**`rxjs#switchMap`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) and do something like this:

> this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
> map((params) => params.id),
> switchMap((id) => this.productsService.getItems(id))
> )

3. You have a typo in a service method: `caRegory` :)

With these changes, we have this:

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  readonly items$: Observable<readonly Product[]>;
  private readonly insertedItemSource$ = new Subject<Product>();
  private readonly insertedItem$ = this.insertedItemSource$.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private readonly productsService: ProductsService
  ) {      
    this.items$ = merge(          
      this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
        map((params) => params.id),
        switchMap((id) => this.productsService.getItems(id))
      ),
      this.insertedItem$
    ).pipe(scan((accumulator, value) => [...accumulator, value]));
  }

  addWidget(): void {
    const item: Product = { color: 'purple', name: 'p-3' };
    this.productsService.add(item).subscribe(itemInserted => this.itemInsertedSource$.next(itemInserted));   
  }
}
```

---

[**STACKBLITZ DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2b5gu7)

Answer (score -2):

I would not suggest you to do it thought async pipe.

You can achieve your needs by creating not Observable items. Also, don't forget to unsubscribe from route params in ngOnDestroy method.

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     id: string;
     items: Product[];
     subscription: Subscription;

     ngOnInit() {
       subscription = this.route.params
        .pipe(
          tap(params => this.id = params.id),
          switchMap(params => loadProducts(params.id))
        )
        .subscribe(
          (items: Product[]) => {
            this.items = items;            
          })


    loadProducts(id: string) {
        return this.productService.get(id);  
     }

    addWidget() {
        let item: any = { name: "p-1", color: "red" } }

        this.productService.add(item)).subscribe(result => {
          if (result) {
           this.items = [...this.items, item];
          } else {
             // notify error 
          }
        })

        // or if server updates item (puts new ids or some new data) then you need to fetch new data.

        this.productService.add(item))
          .pipe(switchMap(() => loadProducts(this.id)))
          .subscribe(items => {
             this.items = items;
          }
        })

    }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.subscription.unsubscribe()
   }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

subscribe to items observable
push new item into items array
Set items observable to observable of updated items

```
addWidget() {
    let item: any = {
        name: "p-1",
        color: "red"
    }
    this.productService.add(item));
    this.items.subscribe(items => {
        items.push(item);
        this.items = of (items);
    }
}
```